# jQuery Carousel Slideshow Navigate to Specific Point(s)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a slideshow carousel using jQuery and overflow hidden in which you can navigate back and forth by adding or subtracting the slide width from the margin-left value.

http://trainingstage.ntistudio.co.uk/slideshows/2/presentation

http://pastebin.com/nYQiEfqB

I now wish to be able to categorise slides into relevant sections, and then navigate to the start of each of these sections, but am unsure how to do this. The main problem is that the content will be dynamic (built with rails) and so hardcoding values into each slideshow is not an option.

Can anyone give me some pointers on where to start for the jQuery so I can shape the rails backend? A similar working project for me to deconstruct might be nice too.

Any hints or tips on this matter are more than welcome. Thank you

Comment: Might be stupid, but can't you get the width by simply <slidewidth>*<slidenumber>?

Comment: Hi @silentw thanks for your reply. Do you mean for setting the initial width or to solve the problem of direct access to a section slide?

Comment: I think I did read the question wrongly. You want to create sections and I though you wanted to place like some numbers on the bottom to navigate to specific slides. Sorry for the mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Give a unique ID to an element on the first page of a section.
- Use jQuery to find the offset() of that element
  http://api.jquery.com/offset/
- Calculate which slide that element exists. 
  Rough algorithm:
  current_slide = Math.ceil($('example').offset().left / slide_width);

Note: You will want to always round up the result of the above operation, because you are initializing the first slide of the show as 1.

Drawbacks: I don't know if offset() will actually report the element based on the full document of the slideshow, or simply the individual slide.

This solution is messy, it might not even work, but perhaps the ideas in it will be useful to you.

Comment: Hi. That helped a lot. It was position(); rather than offset(); which I needed and I just needed to flip the values to negatives. Here's my code
var1 = $('#specific_div').position();
moveto = (var.left) * -1;
$('#presentation_carousel').css('margin-left', moveto );

Answer (score 0):

Categorise each element with an identifier. For example, a cats category, add the class "cats" to each item. Lets say you have dogs after cats and you want to go to dogs.

```
var slideAmount = $('.cats').length * 500 //500 being your viewport width
$('.carouselParent').animate({'left' : -slideAmount});
```

This is very basic logic bit I guess you will see what I am getting at?

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across the **perfect** jQuery slider for your requirements after looking at your website goals.

The **jQuery Local Scroll** handles AJAX content easily and allows for **sub-sections** within your main section.

**jQuery AJAX Local Scroll v1.2.7:** [**Webpage AJAX Demo**](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/ajax/) and the home page is [**HERE**](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2009/03/jquerylocalscroll-127-released.html).

**EDIT:** If the scroller is created dynamically on page load, then take a look at their normal [**non-AJAX version**](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/) that shows a different navigation technique for sections and sub-sections.

**EDIT2:** As far as navigating to and from different elements using jQuery, this plugin can scroll to any element as well, using jQuery selectors.